# calculate the height of character from binarization image OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, image-manipulation

Hello i need to calculate the height of a character from a binarzation image ( see the image bellow):

[image: Binarization image of B]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the row of pixels that have the most black pixels.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

pic = cv2.imread('binarized.png')[:, 50:-50, 0]

np.max(np.sum(1 - (pic//255), axis=0))
```

```
382
```

Using MS Paint, I was able to confirm that the height is 382 by drawing a 382 pixel line next to it. I had to exclude your black borders though.
[image]

Comment: yes i liked the method but i doesn't give the real height ( from the first black pixel, to the last one) i tested it on another images and it failed

Comment: @MohamedSoheib Post more images bruh.

Comment: If this fails, please post more pictures. I can't propose a solution that fits data that I haven't seen. For now, this one works so I dont know what else I could suggest.